# What is correct syntax for using R1C1 and clearing formats of a Range to end of sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a macro that Optimizes the sheet by deleting unused ranges that create very large file sizes. It does this by finding the last used row (column), selecting a range from that last used row (column) to the very bottom-right) of the sheet, and clearing formats and deleting those cells, to delete the unused range that is taking up space.

E.g. if last used row is 50, select range A50 to Bottom right of sheet (aka XFD104873, clear those formats and delete range

I have been able to do this with rows, but not with columns. In the below code, I get a syntax error (shown as 'SYNTAX ERROR' below) when case 2 runs, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I need to use R1C1 notation but for some reason the range(cells(#,#)) aren't picking it up properly.

I think it has to do with the second part in which I do range(cells(#,#)).End(xlDown).end(Toright)

Let me know if i can provide any additional information!

Nick

```
'Option Explicit

Sub Optimize()
    'Call OptimizeSheet(1, "HR_Data")
    Call OptimizeSheet(2, "DomesticAsset_Data")
    'Call OptimizeSheet(3, "InternationalAsset_Data")


End Sub

Sub OptimizeSheet(ByVal choice As Long, ByVal sht As String)

    ' 1 = Rows
    ' 2 = Columns
    ' 3 = Both


    If WorksheetExists(sht) = False Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet doesn't exist, check macro code"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook

    'Last Row and Column Variables
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lc As Long


    'File Size variables
    Dim aFileSize As Long
    Dim bFileSize As Long
    Dim chngFileSize As Long

    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'Get file size before optimizing
    aFileSize = FileLen(Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)


    Select Case choice

        'Rows
        Case 1:

            lr = Worksheets(sht).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
             With Worksheets(sht).Range("A" & lr, Range("A" & lr).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
                .ClearFormats
                .Delete
            End With

        'Columns
        Case 2:

            lc = Worksheets(sht).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
          SYNTAX ERROR HERE
            With Worksheets(sht).Range(Cells(1, lc), RangeCells(1, lc).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
                .ClearFormats
                .Delete
            End With

        'Both
        Case 3:

             lr = Worksheets(sht).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
             With Worksheets(sht).Range("A" & lr, Range("A" & lr).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
                .ClearFormats
                .Delete
            End With


            'chnge
            lc = Worksheets(sht).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
            With Worksheets(sht).Range(Cells(1, lc).Address(), Range(Cells(1, lc).Address()).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
                .ClearFormats
                .Delete
            End With



        Case Else:
            MsgBox "Wrong Choice, check macro code"

    End Select


    Application.ThisWorkbook.Save


    bFileSize = FileLen(Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)

    If aFileSize + bFileSize = 0 Then
            MsgBox "error in filesize"
    End If


        chngFileSize = bFileSize - aFileSize

        If chngFileSize = 0 Then
            MsgBox (sht & " already optimized")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Done. " & (chngFileSize / 1000) & "MB Saved")
        End If





    Exit Sub
   errHandler:
        MsgBox "error on line" & Erl

   End Sub

   Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As 
   Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete columns:

```
With Worksheets(sht)
    .Range(.Cells(1, lc + 1), _
           .Cells(1, lc +1 ).End(xlToRight)).EntireColumn.Delete
End With
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I get Compile error: Expected: expression when I press Enter after .Range(.Cells(1, lc + 1),   Is there supposed to be a period before cells?  **UPDATE** putting it all into one line works instead

Comment: I missed the line continuation underscore (added)

Comment: Ah gotcha thank you!! What does the period before the cells do? Does it associate it to the Worksheet in the With statement?

Comment: Yes - the period links `Cells()` to the `With` statement - without that, Cells() defaults to the ActiveSheet (which may not be the sheet you want, and can cause an error if different from sheet2)